# Azure DataFactory unable to check Version using Definition

Tags: json, azure, azure-data-factory, azure-powershell, policy

Unable to check api version in Definition JSON. Below is the definition along with JSON.

```
    New-AzureRmPolicyDefinition -Policy '{
     "if": {
    "allOf": [
      {
        "field": "type",
        "equals": "Microsoft.DataFactory/factories"
      },
      {
        "field": "apiVersion",
        "equals": "2017-09-01-preview"
      }
    ]
  },
  "then": {
    "effect": "deny"
  }
}' -Name 'DataFactoryVersionRestriction'
```

When I run above definition, it is throwing error related to alias. Can someone please help?

[image]

Comment: Based on the [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-policy/policy-definition#fields), it seems that field not support `apiVersion`.

Answer (score 0):

Use the alias Microsoft.DataFactory/factories/version